# how to copy document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML to clipboard automaticaly?

Tags: javascript

hi all i am using the following code on address bar and works properly by outputting data.

```
javascript: alert(document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML );
```

How i can change the code so it copies the output data to clipboard so i can paste it somewhere later ? I tried following but did not work! Thanks in advance.

did not copy the data to clipboard:

```
javascript: alert(document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML ,document.execCommand("copy"));
```

Comment: `.execCommand('copy')` copies an existing user selection on the page. You can add the HTML text to a textarea, programmatically select all the text in the textarea, and then call `.execCommand('copy')`. Notice, that successful execution depends on the browser settings, some might deny the use of `.execCommand('copy')`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. so how copy content of document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML to clipboard?(it is remote page i can't add textarea to it)

Comment: If you can read the HTML of the `<html>` element on that page, you can add a textarea to the page as well.

Comment: why use: document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0] when you could use: document.documentElement

Answer (score 2):

You should use `clipboard.js` to get a workaround for this with cross browser compatibility.
Read more here 
https://clipboardjs.com/

You can copy anything using

```
clipboard.copy("Your Content");
```

I added the stripped version of clipboard.js on top of your original js code. 
Then converted it to a JavaScript bookmarklet using 
https://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/
and minified.
Just add the following code as a link to the bookmarks bar of the browser and see the functionality or run the sample code.

```html
<a href="javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20clipboard%3D%7B%7D%3Bclipboard.copy%3Dfunction()%7Bfunction%20t()%7Bn%3D!1%2Co%3Dnull%2Cr%26%26window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()%2Cr%3D!1%7Dfunction%20e()%7Bvar%20t%3Ddocument.getSelection()%3Bif(!document.queryCommandEnabled(%22copy%22)%26%26t.isCollapsed)%7Bvar%20e%3Ddocument.createRange()%3Be.selectNodeContents(document.body)%2Ct.removeAllRanges()%2Ct.addRange(e)%2Cr%3D!0%7D%7Dvar%20n%3D!1%2Co%3Dnull%2Cr%3D!1%3Breturn%20document.addEventListener(%22copy%22%2Cfunction(t)%7Bif(n)%7Bfor(var%20e%20in%20o)t.clipboardData.setData(e%2Co%5Be%5D)%3Bt.preventDefault()%7D%7D)%2Cfunction(r)%7Breturn%20new%20Promise(function(i%2Ca)%7Bfunction%20c(n)%7Btry%7Bif(document.execCommand(%22copy%22))t()%2Ci()%3Belse%7Bif(n)throw%20t()%2Cnew%20Error(%22Unable%20to%20copy.%20Perhaps%20it's%20not%20available%20in%20your%20browser%3F%22)%3Be()%2Cc(!0)%7D%7Dcatch(o)%7Bt()%2Ca(o)%7D%7Dn%3D!0%2C%22string%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20r%3Fo%3D%7B%22text%2Fplain%22%3Ar%7D%3Ar%20instanceof%20Node%3Fo%3D%7B%22text%2Fhtml%22%3A(new%20XMLSerializer).serializeToString(r)%7D%3Ar%20instanceof%20Object%3Fo%3Dr%3Aa(%22Invalid%20data%20type.%20Must%20be%20string%2C%20DOM%20node%2C%20or%20an%20object%20mapping%20MIME%20types%20to%20strings.%22)%2Cc(!1)%7D)%7D%7D()%2Cclipboard.paste%3Dfunction()%7Bvar%20t%2Ce%2Cn%3D!1%3Breturn%20document.addEventListener(%22paste%22%2Cfunction(o)%7Bif(n)%7Bn%3D!1%2Co.preventDefault()%3Bvar%20r%3Dt%3Bt%3Dnull%2Cr(o.clipboardData.getData(e))%7D%7D)%2Cfunction(o)%7Breturn%20new%20Promise(function(r%2Ci)%7Bn%3D!0%2Ct%3Dr%2Ce%3Do%7C%7C%22text%2Fplain%22%3Btry%7Bdocument.execCommand(%22paste%22)%7C%7C(n%3D!1%2Ci(new%20Error(%22Unable%20to%20paste.%20Pasting%20only%20works%20in%20Internet%20Explorer%20at%20the%20moment.%22)))%7Dcatch(a)%7Bn%3D!1%2Ci(new%20Error(a))%7D%7D)%7D%7D()%2C%22undefined%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20ClipboardEvent%26%26%22undefined%22!%3Dtypeof%20window.clipboardData%26%26%22undefined%22!%3Dtypeof%20window.clipboardData.setData%26%26(!function(t)%7Bfunction%20e(t%2Ce)%7Breturn%20function()%7Bt.apply(e%2Carguments)%7D%7Dfunction%20n(t)%7Bif(%22object%22!%3Dtypeof%20this)throw%20new%20TypeError(%22Promises%20must%20be%20constructed%20via%20new%22)%3Bif(%22function%22!%3Dtypeof%20t)throw%20new%20TypeError(%22not%20a%20function%22)%3Bthis._state%3Dnull%2Cthis._value%3Dnull%2Cthis._deferreds%3D%5B%5D%2Cu(t%2Ce(r%2Cthis)%2Ce(i%2Cthis))%7Dfunction%20o(t)%7Bvar%20e%3Dthis%3Breturn%20null%3D%3D%3Dthis._state%3Fvoid%20this._deferreds.push(t)%3Avoid%20s(function()%7Bvar%20n%3De._state%3Ft.onFulfilled%3At.onRejected%3Bif(null%3D%3D%3Dn)return%20void(e._state%3Ft.resolve%3At.reject)(e._value)%3Bvar%20o%3Btry%7Bo%3Dn(e._value)%7Dcatch(r)%7Breturn%20void%20t.reject(r)%7Dt.resolve(o)%7D)%7Dfunction%20r(t)%7Btry%7Bif(t%3D%3D%3Dthis)throw%20new%20TypeError(%22A%20promise%20cannot%20be%20resolved%20with%20itself.%22)%3Bif(t%26%26(%22object%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20t%7C%7C%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20t))%7Bvar%20n%3Dt.then%3Bif(%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20n)return%20void%20u(e(n%2Ct)%2Ce(r%2Cthis)%2Ce(i%2Cthis))%7Dthis._state%3D!0%2Cthis._value%3Dt%2Ca.call(this)%7Dcatch(o)%7Bi.call(this%2Co)%7D%7Dfunction%20i(t)%7Bthis._state%3D!1%2Cthis._value%3Dt%2Ca.call(this)%7Dfunction%20a()%7Bfor(var%20t%3D0%2Ce%3Dthis._deferreds.length%3Be%3Et%3Bt%2B%2B)o.call(this%2Cthis._deferreds%5Bt%5D)%3Bthis._deferreds%3Dnull%7Dfunction%20c(t%2Ce%2Cn%2Co)%7Bthis.onFulfilled%3D%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20t%3Ft%3Anull%2Cthis.onRejected%3D%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20e%3Fe%3Anull%2Cthis.resolve%3Dn%2Cthis.reject%3Do%7Dfunction%20u(t%2Ce%2Cn)%7Bvar%20o%3D!1%3Btry%7Bt(function(t)%7Bo%7C%7C(o%3D!0%2Ce(t))%7D%2Cfunction(t)%7Bo%7C%7C(o%3D!0%2Cn(t))%7D)%7Dcatch(r)%7Bif(o)return%3Bo%3D!0%2Cn(r)%7D%7Dvar%20s%3Dn.immediateFn%7C%7C%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20setImmediate%26%26setImmediate%7C%7Cfunction(t)%7BsetTimeout(t%2C1)%7D%2Cl%3DArray.isArray%7C%7Cfunction(t)%7Breturn%22%5Bobject%20Array%5D%22%3D%3D%3DObject.prototype.toString.call(t)%7D%3Bn.prototype%5B%22catch%22%5D%3Dfunction(t)%7Breturn%20this.then(null%2Ct)%7D%2Cn.prototype.then%3Dfunction(t%2Ce)%7Bvar%20r%3Dthis%3Breturn%20new%20n(function(n%2Ci)%7Bo.call(r%2Cnew%20c(t%2Ce%2Cn%2Ci))%7D)%7D%2Cn.all%3Dfunction()%7Bvar%20t%3DArray.prototype.slice.call(1%3D%3D%3Darguments.length%26%26l(arguments%5B0%5D)%3Farguments%5B0%5D%3Aarguments)%3Breturn%20new%20n(function(e%2Cn)%7Bfunction%20o(i%2Ca)%7Btry%7Bif(a%26%26(%22object%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20a%7C%7C%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20a))%7Bvar%20c%3Da.then%3Bif(%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20c)return%20void%20c.call(a%2Cfunction(t)%7Bo(i%2Ct)%7D%2Cn)%7Dt%5Bi%5D%3Da%2C0%3D%3D%3D--r%26%26e(t)%7Dcatch(u)%7Bn(u)%7D%7Dif(0%3D%3D%3Dt.length)return%20e(%5B%5D)%3Bfor(var%20r%3Dt.length%2Ci%3D0%3Bi%3Ct.length%3Bi%2B%2B)o(i%2Ct%5Bi%5D)%7D)%7D%2Cn.resolve%3Dfunction(t)%7Breturn%20t%26%26%22object%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20t%26%26t.constructor%3D%3D%3Dn%3Ft%3Anew%20n(function(e)%7Be(t)%7D)%7D%2Cn.reject%3Dfunction(t)%7Breturn%20new%20n(function(e%2Cn)%7Bn(t)%7D)%7D%2Cn.race%3Dfunction(t)%7Breturn%20new%20n(function(e%2Cn)%7Bfor(var%20o%3D0%2Cr%3Dt.length%3Br%3Eo%3Bo%2B%2B)t%5Bo%5D.then(e%2Cn)%7D)%7D%2C%22undefined%22!%3Dtypeof%20module%26%26module.exports%3Fmodule.exports%3Dn%3At.Promise%7C%7C(t.Promise%3Dn)%7D(this)%2Cclipboard.copy%3Dfunction(t)%7Breturn%20new%20Promise(function(e%2Cn)%7Bif(%22string%22!%3Dtypeof%20t%26%26!(%22text%2Fplain%22in%20t))throw%20new%20Error(%22You%20must%20provide%20a%20text%2Fplain%20type.%22)%3Bvar%20o%3D%22string%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20t%3Ft%3At%5B%22text%2Fplain%22%5D%2Cr%3Dwindow.clipboardData.setData(%22Text%22%2Co)%3Br%3Fe()%3An(new%20Error(%22Copying%20was%20rejected.%22))%7D)%7D%2Cclipboard.paste%3Dfunction()%7Breturn%20new%20Promise(function(t%2Ce)%7Bvar%20n%3Dwindow.clipboardData.getData(%22Text%22)%3Bn%3Ft(n)%3Ae(new%20Error(%22Pasting%20was%20rejected.%22))%7D)%7D)%3Bclipboard.copy(document.getElementsByTagName(%22html%22)%5B0%5D.innerHTML)%3Balert(document.getElementsByTagName(%22html%22)%5B0%5D.innerHTML)%7D)()">Click here</a>
```

The required code is as below.

```
javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20clipboard%3D%7B%7D%3Bclipboard.copy%3Dfunction()%7Bfunction%20t()%7Bn%3D!1%2Co%3Dnull%2Cr%26%26window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()%2Cr%3D!1%7Dfunction%20e()%7Bvar%20t%3Ddocument.getSelection()%3Bif(!document.queryCommandEnabled(%22copy%22)%26%26t.isCollapsed)%7Bvar%20e%3Ddocument.createRange()%3Be.selectNodeContents(document.body)%2Ct.removeAllRanges()%2Ct.addRange(e)%2Cr%3D!0%7D%7Dvar%20n%3D!1%2Co%3Dnull%2Cr%3D!1%3Breturn%20document.addEventListener(%22copy%22%2Cfunction(t)%7Bif(n)%7Bfor(var%20e%20in%20o)t.clipboardData.setData(e%2Co%5Be%5D)%3Bt.preventDefault()%7D%7D)%2Cfunction(r)%7Breturn%20new%20Promise(function(i%2Ca)%7Bfunction%20c(n)%7Btry%7Bif(document.execCommand(%22copy%22))t()%2Ci()%3Belse%7Bif(n)throw%20t()%2Cnew%20Error(%22Unable%20to%20copy.%20Perhaps%20it's%20not%20available%20in%20your%20browser%3F%22)%3Be()%2Cc(!0)%7D%7Dcatch(o)%7Bt()%2Ca(o)%7D%7Dn%3D!0%2C%22string%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20r%3Fo%3D%7B%22text%2Fplain%22%3Ar%7D%3Ar%20instanceof%20Node%3Fo%3D%7B%22text%2Fhtml%22%3A(new%20XMLSerializer).serializeToString(r)%7D%3Ar%20instanceof%20Object%3Fo%3Dr%3Aa(%22Invalid%20data%20type.%20Must%20be%20string%2C%20DOM%20node%2C%20or%20an%20object%20mapping%20MIME%20types%20to%20strings.%22)%2Cc(!1)%7D)%7D%7D()%2Cclipboard.paste%3Dfunction()%7Bvar%20t%2Ce%2Cn%3D!1%3Breturn%20document.addEventListener(%22paste%22%2Cfunction(o)%7Bif(n)%7Bn%3D!1%2Co.preventDefault()%3Bvar%20r%3Dt%3Bt%3Dnull%2Cr(o.clipboardData.getData(e))%7D%7D)%2Cfunction(o)%7Breturn%20new%20Promise(function(r%2Ci)%7Bn%3D!0%2Ct%3Dr%2Ce%3Do%7C%7C%22text%2Fplain%22%3Btry%7Bdocument.execCommand(%22paste%22)%7C%7C(n%3D!1%2Ci(new%20Error(%22Unable%20to%20paste.%20Pasting%20only%20works%20in%20Internet%20Explorer%20at%20the%20moment.%22)))%7Dcatch(a)%7Bn%3D!1%2Ci(new%20Error(a))%7D%7D)%7D%7D()%2C%22undefined%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20ClipboardEvent%26%26%22undefined%22!%3Dtypeof%20window.clipboardData%26%26%22undefined%22!%3Dtypeof%20window.clipboardData.setData%26%26(!function(t)%7Bfunction%20e(t%2Ce)%7Breturn%20function()%7Bt.apply(e%2Carguments)%7D%7Dfunction%20n(t)%7Bif(%22object%22!%3Dtypeof%20this)throw%20new%20TypeError(%22Promises%20must%20be%20constructed%20via%20new%22)%3Bif(%22function%22!%3Dtypeof%20t)throw%20new%20TypeError(%22not%20a%20function%22)%3Bthis._state%3Dnull%2Cthis._value%3Dnull%2Cthis._deferreds%3D%5B%5D%2Cu(t%2Ce(r%2Cthis)%2Ce(i%2Cthis))%7Dfunction%20o(t)%7Bvar%20e%3Dthis%3Breturn%20null%3D%3D%3Dthis._state%3Fvoid%20this._deferreds.push(t)%3Avoid%20s(function()%7Bvar%20n%3De._state%3Ft.onFulfilled%3At.onRejected%3Bif(null%3D%3D%3Dn)return%20void(e._state%3Ft.resolve%3At.reject)(e._value)%3Bvar%20o%3Btry%7Bo%3Dn(e._value)%7Dcatch(r)%7Breturn%20void%20t.reject(r)%7Dt.resolve(o)%7D)%7Dfunction%20r(t)%7Btry%7Bif(t%3D%3D%3Dthis)throw%20new%20TypeError(%22A%20promise%20cannot%20be%20resolved%20with%20itself.%22)%3Bif(t%26%26(%22object%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20t%7C%7C%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20t))%7Bvar%20n%3Dt.then%3Bif(%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20n)return%20void%20u(e(n%2Ct)%2Ce(r%2Cthis)%2Ce(i%2Cthis))%7Dthis._state%3D!0%2Cthis._value%3Dt%2Ca.call(this)%7Dcatch(o)%7Bi.call(this%2Co)%7D%7Dfunction%20i(t)%7Bthis._state%3D!1%2Cthis._value%3Dt%2Ca.call(this)%7Dfunction%20a()%7Bfor(var%20t%3D0%2Ce%3Dthis._deferreds.length%3Be%3Et%3Bt%2B%2B)o.call(this%2Cthis._deferreds%5Bt%5D)%3Bthis._deferreds%3Dnull%7Dfunction%20c(t%2Ce%2Cn%2Co)%7Bthis.onFulfilled%3D%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20t%3Ft%3Anull%2Cthis.onRejected%3D%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20e%3Fe%3Anull%2Cthis.resolve%3Dn%2Cthis.reject%3Do%7Dfunction%20u(t%2Ce%2Cn)%7Bvar%20o%3D!1%3Btry%7Bt(function(t)%7Bo%7C%7C(o%3D!0%2Ce(t))%7D%2Cfunction(t)%7Bo%7C%7C(o%3D!0%2Cn(t))%7D)%7Dcatch(r)%7Bif(o)return%3Bo%3D!0%2Cn(r)%7D%7Dvar%20s%3Dn.immediateFn%7C%7C%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20setImmediate%26%26setImmediate%7C%7Cfunction(t)%7BsetTimeout(t%2C1)%7D%2Cl%3DArray.isArray%7C%7Cfunction(t)%7Breturn%22%5Bobject%20Array%5D%22%3D%3D%3DObject.prototype.toString.call(t)%7D%3Bn.prototype%5B%22catch%22%5D%3Dfunction(t)%7Breturn%20this.then(null%2Ct)%7D%2Cn.prototype.then%3Dfunction(t%2Ce)%7Bvar%20r%3Dthis%3Breturn%20new%20n(function(n%2Ci)%7Bo.call(r%2Cnew%20c(t%2Ce%2Cn%2Ci))%7D)%7D%2Cn.all%3Dfunction()%7Bvar%20t%3DArray.prototype.slice.call(1%3D%3D%3Darguments.length%26%26l(arguments%5B0%5D)%3Farguments%5B0%5D%3Aarguments)%3Breturn%20new%20n(function(e%2Cn)%7Bfunction%20o(i%2Ca)%7Btry%7Bif(a%26%26(%22object%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20a%7C%7C%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20a))%7Bvar%20c%3Da.then%3Bif(%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20c)return%20void%20c.call(a%2Cfunction(t)%7Bo(i%2Ct)%7D%2Cn)%7Dt%5Bi%5D%3Da%2C0%3D%3D%3D--r%26%26e(t)%7Dcatch(u)%7Bn(u)%7D%7Dif(0%3D%3D%3Dt.length)return%20e(%5B%5D)%3Bfor(var%20r%3Dt.length%2Ci%3D0%3Bi%3Ct.length%3Bi%2B%2B)o(i%2Ct%5Bi%5D)%7D)%7D%2Cn.resolve%3Dfunction(t)%7Breturn%20t%26%26%22object%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20t%26%26t.constructor%3D%3D%3Dn%3Ft%3Anew%20n(function(e)%7Be(t)%7D)%7D%2Cn.reject%3Dfunction(t)%7Breturn%20new%20n(function(e%2Cn)%7Bn(t)%7D)%7D%2Cn.race%3Dfunction(t)%7Breturn%20new%20n(function(e%2Cn)%7Bfor(var%20o%3D0%2Cr%3Dt.length%3Br%3Eo%3Bo%2B%2B)t%5Bo%5D.then(e%2Cn)%7D)%7D%2C%22undefined%22!%3Dtypeof%20module%26%26module.exports%3Fmodule.exports%3Dn%3At.Promise%7C%7C(t.Promise%3Dn)%7D(this)%2Cclipboard.copy%3Dfunction(t)%7Breturn%20new%20Promise(function(e%2Cn)%7Bif(%22string%22!%3Dtypeof%20t%26%26!(%22text%2Fplain%22in%20t))throw%20new%20Error(%22You%20must%20provide%20a%20text%2Fplain%20type.%22)%3Bvar%20o%3D%22string%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20t%3Ft%3At%5B%22text%2Fplain%22%5D%2Cr%3Dwindow.clipboardData.setData(%22Text%22%2Co)%3Br%3Fe()%3An(new%20Error(%22Copying%20was%20rejected.%22))%7D)%7D%2Cclipboard.paste%3Dfunction()%7Breturn%20new%20Promise(function(t%2Ce)%7Bvar%20n%3Dwindow.clipboardData.getData(%22Text%22)%3Bn%3Ft(n)%3Ae(new%20Error(%22Pasting%20was%20rejected.%22))%7D)%7D)%3Bclipboard.copy(document.getElementsByTagName(%22html%22)%5B0%5D.innerHTML)%3Balert(document.getElementsByTagName(%22html%22)%5B0%5D.innerHTML)%7D)()
```

Comment: Looks like clipboardjs internally uses the same technique I've described in my first comment ..?

Comment: @Teemu yep. But it has polyfills for IE and Safari

Comment: By my experience, IE doesn't need polyfills when using clipboard command identifiers via `execCommand`, they've been there since IE5.

Comment: @Teemu You should definitely write a open source clipboard library. ;)

Comment: Looks like Naresh Pingale is in the midway already, let's  'em finish the job = ).

Comment: Most are doing is re-inventing the wheel :)

Comment: Thanks for all replies .Thusitha i tried your code on android default browser but unfortunately nothing copied to clipboard! I need somehow to be able to copy the html source code so i analyze it later.Is there away to pass the html source code to a php scrip url so that php url place it on textarea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript: var temp = document.createElement("textarea");
document.body.appendChild(temp);
temp.value = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML;
temp.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
temp.remove()
```

The code you are looking for is this where you select the text before executing "copy". But unfortunately even this wont work for you as all document.execCommand('copy') calls must take place as a direct result of a user action, e.g. click event handler. This is a measure to prevent messing with the users clipboard when they don't expect it. And according to my understanding of your post is that you are looking for a small script which you could paste in your address bar and copy the content.
Check [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands?hl=en) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

### Heading

```html
<a href="javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20clipboard%3D%7B%7D%3Bclipboard.copy%3Dfunction()%7Bfunction%20t()%7Bn%3D!1%2Co%3Dnull%2Cr%26%26window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()%2Cr%3D!1%7Dfunction%20e()%7Bvar%20t%3Ddocument.getSelection()%3Bif(!document.queryCommandEnabled(%22copy%22)%26%26t.isCollapsed)%7Bvar%20e%3Ddocument.createRange()%3Be.selectNodeContents(document.body)%2Ct.removeAllRanges()%2Ct.addRange(e)%2Cr%3D!0%7D%7Dvar%20n%3D!1%2Co%3Dnull%2Cr%3D!1%3Breturn%20document.addEventListener(%22copy%22%2Cfunction(t)%7Bif(n)%7Bfor(var%20e%20in%20o)t.clipboardData.setData(e%2Co%5Be%5D)%3Bt.preventDefault()%7D%7D)%2Cfunction(r)%7Breturn%20new%20Promise(function(i%2Ca)%7Bfunction%20c(n)%7Btry%7Bif(document.execCommand(%22copy%22))t()%2Ci()%3Belse%7Bif(n)throw%20t()%2Cnew%20Error(%22Unable%20to%20copy.%20Perhaps%20it's%20not%20available%20in%20your%20browser%3F%22)%3Be()%2Cc(!0)%7D%7Dcatch(o)%7Bt()%2Ca(o)%7D%7Dn%3D!0%2C%22string%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20r%3Fo%3D%7B%22text%2Fplain%22%3Ar%7D%3Ar%20instanceof%20Node%3Fo%3D%7B%22text%2Fhtml%22%3A(new%20XMLSerializer).serializeToString(r)%7D%3Ar%20instanceof%20Object%3Fo%3Dr%3Aa(%22Invalid%20data%20type.%20Must%20be%20string%2C%20DOM%20node%2C%20or%20an%20object%20mapping%20MIME%20types%20to%20strings.%22)%2Cc(!1)%7D)%7D%7D()%2Cclipboard.paste%3Dfunction()%7Bvar%20t%2Ce%2Cn%3D!1%3Breturn%20document.addEventListener(%22paste%22%2Cfunction(o)%7Bif(n)%7Bn%3D!1%2Co.preventDefault()%3Bvar%20r%3Dt%3Bt%3Dnull%2Cr(o.clipboardData.getData(e))%7D%7D)%2Cfunction(o)%7Breturn%20new%20Promise(function(r%2Ci)%7Bn%3D!0%2Ct%3Dr%2Ce%3Do%7C%7C%22text%2Fplain%22%3Btry%7Bdocument.execCommand(%22paste%22)%7C%7C(n%3D!1%2Ci(new%20Error(%22Unable%20to%20paste.%20Pasting%20only%20works%20in%20Internet%20Explorer%20at%20the%20moment.%22)))%7Dcatch(a)%7Bn%3D!1%2Ci(new%20Error(a))%7D%7D)%7D%7D()%2C%22undefined%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20ClipboardEvent%26%26%22undefined%22!%3Dtypeof%20window.clipboardData%26%26%22undefined%22!%3Dtypeof%20window.clipboardData.setData%26%26(!function(t)%7Bfunction%20e(t%2Ce)%7Breturn%20function()%7Bt.apply(e%2Carguments)%7D%7Dfunction%20n(t)%7Bif(%22object%22!%3Dtypeof%20this)throw%20new%20TypeError(%22Promises%20must%20be%20constructed%20via%20new%22)%3Bif(%22function%22!%3Dtypeof%20t)throw%20new%20TypeError(%22not%20a%20function%22)%3Bthis._state%3Dnull%2Cthis._value%3Dnull%2Cthis._deferreds%3D%5B%5D%2Cu(t%2Ce(r%2Cthis)%2Ce(i%2Cthis))%7Dfunction%20o(t)%7Bvar%20e%3Dthis%3Breturn%20null%3D%3D%3Dthis._state%3Fvoid%20this._deferreds.push(t)%3Avoid%20s(function()%7Bvar%20n%3De._state%3Ft.onFulfilled%3At.onRejected%3Bif(null%3D%3D%3Dn)return%20void(e._state%3Ft.resolve%3At.reject)(e._value)%3Bvar%20o%3Btry%7Bo%3Dn(e._value)%7Dcatch(r)%7Breturn%20void%20t.reject(r)%7Dt.resolve(o)%7D)%7Dfunction%20r(t)%7Btry%7Bif(t%3D%3D%3Dthis)throw%20new%20TypeError(%22A%20promise%20cannot%20be%20resolved%20with%20itself.%22)%3Bif(t%26%26(%22object%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20t%7C%7C%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20t))%7Bvar%20n%3Dt.then%3Bif(%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20n)return%20void%20u(e(n%2Ct)%2Ce(r%2Cthis)%2Ce(i%2Cthis))%7Dthis._state%3D!0%2Cthis._value%3Dt%2Ca.call(this)%7Dcatch(o)%7Bi.call(this%2Co)%7D%7Dfunction%20i(t)%7Bthis._state%3D!1%2Cthis._value%3Dt%2Ca.call(this)%7Dfunction%20a()%7Bfor(var%20t%3D0%2Ce%3Dthis._deferreds.length%3Be%3Et%3Bt%2B%2B)o.call(this%2Cthis._deferreds%5Bt%5D)%3Bthis._deferreds%3Dnull%7Dfunction%20c(t%2Ce%2Cn%2Co)%7Bthis.onFulfilled%3D%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20t%3Ft%3Anull%2Cthis.onRejected%3D%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20e%3Fe%3Anull%2Cthis.resolve%3Dn%2Cthis.reject%3Do%7Dfunction%20u(t%2Ce%2Cn)%7Bvar%20o%3D!1%3Btry%7Bt(function(t)%7Bo%7C%7C(o%3D!0%2Ce(t))%7D%2Cfunction(t)%7Bo%7C%7C(o%3D!0%2Cn(t))%7D)%7Dcatch(r)%7Bif(o)return%3Bo%3D!0%2Cn(r)%7D%7Dvar%20s%3Dn.immediateFn%7C%7C%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20setImmediate%26%26setImmediate%7C%7Cfunction(t)%7BsetTimeout(t%2C1)%7D%2Cl%3DArray.isArray%7C%7Cfunction(t)%7Breturn%22%5Bobject%20Array%5D%22%3D%3D%3DObject.prototype.toString.call(t)%7D%3Bn.prototype%5B%22catch%22%5D%3Dfunction(t)%7Breturn%20this.then(null%2Ct)%7D%2Cn.prototype.then%3Dfunction(t%2Ce)%7Bvar%20r%3Dthis%3Breturn%20new%20n(function(n%2Ci)%7Bo.call(r%2Cnew%20c(t%2Ce%2Cn%2Ci))%7D)%7D%2Cn.all%3Dfunction()%7Bvar%20t%3DArray.prototype.slice.call(1%3D%3D%3Darguments.length%26%26l(arguments%5B0%5D)%3Farguments%5B0%5D%3Aarguments)%3Breturn%20new%20n(function(e%2Cn)%7Bfunction%20o(i%2Ca)%7Btry%7Bif(a%26%26(%22object%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20a%7C%7C%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20a))%7Bvar%20c%3Da.then%3Bif(%22function%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20c)return%20void%20c.call(a%2Cfunction(t)%7Bo(i%2Ct)%7D%2Cn)%7Dt%5Bi%5D%3Da%2C0%3D%3D%3D--r%26%26e(t)%7Dcatch(u)%7Bn(u)%7D%7Dif(0%3D%3D%3Dt.length)return%20e(%5B%5D)%3Bfor(var%20r%3Dt.length%2Ci%3D0%3Bi%3Ct.length%3Bi%2B%2B)o(i%2Ct%5Bi%5D)%7D)%7D%2Cn.resolve%3Dfunction(t)%7Breturn%20t%26%26%22object%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20t%26%26t.constructor%3D%3D%3Dn%3Ft%3Anew%20n(function(e)%7Be(t)%7D)%7D%2Cn.reject%3Dfunction(t)%7Breturn%20new%20n(function(e%2Cn)%7Bn(t)%7D)%7D%2Cn.race%3Dfunction(t)%7Breturn%20new%20n(function(e%2Cn)%7Bfor(var%20o%3D0%2Cr%3Dt.length%3Br%3Eo%3Bo%2B%2B)t%5Bo%5D.then(e%2Cn)%7D)%7D%2C%22undefined%22!%3Dtypeof%20module%26%26module.exports%3Fmodule.exports%3Dn%3At.Promise%7C%7C(t.Promise%3Dn)%7D(this)%2Cclipboard.copy%3Dfunction(t)%7Breturn%20new%20Promise(function(e%2Cn)%7Bif(%22string%22!%3Dtypeof%20t%26%26!(%22text%2Fplain%22in%20t))throw%20new%20Error(%22You%20must%20provide%20a%20text%2Fplain%20type.%22)%3Bvar%20o%3D%22string%22%3D%3Dtypeof%20t%3Ft%3At%5B%22text%2Fplain%22%5D%2Cr%3Dwindow.clipboardData.setData(%22Text%22%2Co)**strong text**%3Br%3Fe()%3An(new%20Error(%22Copying%20was%20rejected.%22))%7D)%7D%2Cclipboard.paste%3Dfunction()%7Breturn%20new%20Promise(function(t%2Ce)%7Bvar%20n%3Dwindow.clipboardData.getData(%22Text%22)%3Bn%3Ft(n)%3Ae(new%20Error(%22Pasting%20was%20rejected.%22))%7D)%7D)%3Bclipboard.copy(document.getElementsByTagName(%22html%22)%5B0%5D.innerHTML)%3Balert(document.getElementsByTagName(%22html%22)%5B0%5D.innerHTML)%7D)()">Click here</a>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).